# Given any countable collection of non-zero vectors in a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $\{\alpha_i\}$ be a countable collection of non-zero vectors in a Hilbert space $H$. Is there exist a vector $\beta \in H$ such that $\langle \beta , \alpha_i \rangle \neq 0$ for all $i$ ?

Comment: Depends on the space $H$.

Comment: Could you tell some  spaces where it does not happen and it does

Answer (score 0):

You're asking whether the union of a countable collection of orthogonal compliments of vectors can be the whole Hilbert space. The answer is "no", by the Baire category theorem, for instance.  So the answer to your question is "yes", such an element always exists.

Comment: Can you explicitly build a vector given a countable collection of non-zero vectors?

Comment: Good question. I don't know.